# Prompt the user to save html file to the folder they select on their computer

Tags: php

I have a piece of code to let the user save a html file (the 'history' list of his actions in the site) to the folder or location he wants on his/her computer. It's a start but it just saves the file on the Download folder of the browser used.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.basename($hFile).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($hFile));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($hFile);
```

Do you know what is missing in order to let the user choose where to save this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of behavior is browser-dependent and you have no control over it.

You've done what you can do to force a download.  Now, it's up to the user, their browser, and configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we probably have no control over that. I just wanted to see if there's a way for the popup to have a browse button or something to let the user select a location - not only the 'download' folder of the browser.